# correlated subquery execution when it has more than one subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have doubts about correlated sub-query execution  When there is more than one sub-query.

I know about correlated sub-query execution when there is only one sub-query. But, if there is more than one I am not able to understand.

I have referred to many books and web sites but I could not find a suitable answer.

Below are two queries. I know how query1 executes but how does query2?

query 1:

```
select e.ename, e.city 
  from emp1 e 
 where exists ( select f.ename 
                  from emp2 f  
                 where f.ename = ’ajay’ 
                   and e.city = f.city
                       )
```

query2:

```
select e.ename 
  from employee e 
 where exists ( select ‘x’ 
                  from emp_company c 
                 where e.ename = c.ename  
                   and exists ( select ‘x’ 
                                  from company m 
                                 where c.cname = m.cname 
                                   and m.city = ’bombay’ 
                                       )
                       )
```

1. In the first step of execution of query1 the employee table’s first row `ename`, `city` considered.
2. In the second step of execution of query1, the considered city from main query is compared with every row of `emp2`.
3. The, while comparing city from the main query with every row of emp2; if any row satisfies condition that rows ename is added to a list.
4. The formed list is returned to the main query.
5. If the returned list is not empty then `exists` evaluates to true. Then `emp1` table’s `ename`, `city` added output.
6. The `ename`, `city` from `emp1` are selected from second row of `emp1` table.

Can you please explain the execution of query2 as I explained query1?

Comment: As you explained query1? Where? I see no explanation! While you are explaining things, please explain why you aren't using joins.

Comment: I have completely re-written your question to make it readable and hopefully make sense. If you disagree with anything please feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Don't think in ordered steps. The DBMS is free to produce any kind of plan as long as the end result corresponds to what your six-step method produces. That could even be a cartesian product + trimming down anything that does not satisfy the where and exists clauses.

Comment: I thik you're overanalyzing this. Make a simplifying assumption - if you can code it, the database can execute it. Whether the database can execute your query *efficiently* is Yet Another Issue, but don't worry about the HOW - worry about the WHAT and let the database worry about the HOW. That's one of the nice things about relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

What your second query says is: give me employees if there exits companies they work in (first subquery) and if such companies (taken from the first subquery) exist in Bombay (second subquery). You would get the same result with the following, probably more effecient, select statement:

```
select e.ename 
from employee e,
  emp_company ec,
  company c 
where e.ename = ec.ename
  and ec.cname = c.cname
  and c.name = 'bombay'
```

That's for the logic. If you are interested in details on how *Mr. Oracle* fetches the rows you could take a look at **Query Explain Plan**.